# Como colocar uma div sobrepondo outra usando apenas posição relativa?

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

Podem achar desnecessário, mas é por causa de um efeito que eu quero usar, e minha dúvida é essa, se tem como colocar uma div sobrepondo outra usando apenas posição relativa nas duas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

**Usando `position relative`**

```css
section div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
section div:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -130px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

**Usando `position relative`** e **`float`**

```css
section div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
section div:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

**Usando `position absolute`**

```css
section div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
section div:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma é usar o `position:absolute;`

porém, você pode setar assim como o seguinte exemplo também

```
top:-2em; /*Vai subir o elemento 2em em relação ao pai*/
```

*lembrando que você precisa colocar um `float` no elemento

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso você vai precisar da *div* pai e da *div* filho.

Segue abaixo:

```
<div class="x"> 
    <div class="y"></div> 
</div>
```

No css o código ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
div.x{ position:absolute; }
div.x .y { position:relative; }
```

Link:

http://codepen.io/profissionalweb04/pen/jAQovJ